# One shot ChangeListener in JavaFX

Tags: javafx-8

Is there any way to make a listener fire once and remove itself?

```
    for(Spec spec : specs){
        spec.myProperty().addListener((obs,ov,nv) -> {
            if (nv.longValue() > 0){
                //do whatever
                spec.myProperty().removeListener(this);
            }  
        });
    }
```

That code won't work.  I can only think of complicated solutions to this seemingly simple problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using an anonymous inner class instead of a lambda expression?

```
IntegerProperty property = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

InvalidationListener listener = new InvalidationListener() {

    @Override
    public void invalidated(Observable observable) {
        //TODO do something
        property.removeListener(this);
    }
};

property.addListener(listener);
```

The answer was partly in the comments so I'll add my [brian] solution here.

```
public void someMethod(){
    for(Spec spec : specs){
        spec.myProperty().addListener(listener);
    }
}

ChangeListener<Number> listener = new ChangeListener<Number>() {
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> obs, Number ov, Number nv) {
        Spec spec = (Spec)((SimpleLongProperty)obs).getBean();
        spec.myProperty().removeListener(this);
    }
};
```

Note, when I create myProperty in the Spec class I use the full constructor to specify the bean.  `new SimpleLongProperty(this, "myProperty", 0l);`

Even doing this you still can't use a lambda to remove `this`.

Comment: I tried, but I guess my question isn't complete.  I go through a list objects  and need to do one thing if a certain property changes.  The question would be how to pass an object reference to the listener in you case.  I'll try and rewrite the question better.

Comment: @brian Maybe this is something for you: https://eckig.github.io/blog/2014/09/01/using-javafxs-properties/ (Create a single Listener instance and attach it to all items in your list)

Comment: Doh!, I take it the bean is the class that the property is of?  That's perfect, I've never used the beans.  Good writeup thanks.

Comment: Ypu can put whatever you like as bean into a JavaFX property, but it is meant to be the bean class (as the name suggests) or in other words the class that holds the property.

Comment: @brian Thanks for the edit. And yes, lambdas are not anononymous inner classes, that leaves us with both benefits and some drawbacks. But mostly I find it pretty usefull to use `this` to directly address the "outer class" around the lambda.

Comment: Why not remove the listener directly from `obs`? Why do you go through all the trouble of getting of a property just to get back that same property?